# Очень долгое выполнение запросов через DbContext

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Стоит PostgreSQL. В ней таблица с чуть более, чем 300 тысяч строк.

Если я выполняю вот такой запрос в pgAdmin, то он выполняется за доли секунды (~300мс):

```
SELECT *
FROM public."Movies"
WHERE vote_count > 100
ORDER BY vote_average DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Если же выполнить аналогичный запрос в приложении ASP.Net Core, то страница грузится почти минуту (~50c), но если не использовать БД, а просто дать готовую коллекцию аля `new Movie[] { ... }`, то загрузка практически мгновенная.

```
//в классе контроллера
private IMovieRepository repository;

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(repository.Movies
                            .Where(m => m.VoteCount > 100)
                            .OrderByDescending(m => m.VoteAverage)
                            .Take(10));
}

//класс для работы с данными
public class EFMovieRepository : IMovieRepository
{

    private TMDbContext context;

    public EFMovieRepository(TMDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies => context.Movies;

}

//класс контекста
public class TMDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TMDbContext() : base() { }

    public TMDbContext(DbContextOptions<TMDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

}

//конфигурация в классе Startup
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                            .Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TMDbContext>(option =>
        option.UseNpgsql(
            Configuration["Data:Movies:ConnectionString"]));
    services.AddTransient<IMovieRepository, EFMovieRepository>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Использую `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`

В чём кроется проблема? Может у меня с конфигурацией что-то не так или может запрос надо составлять более правильно? Почему SQL запрос в pgAdmin во столько раз быстрее запроса через провайдера?

**UPD:** Изменил код метода на:

```
public string Index()
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    var movies = repository.Movies
                            .Where(m => m.VoteCount > 100)
                            .OrderByDescending(m => m.VoteAverage)
                            .Take(10).ToList();

    return (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString();
}
```

Возвращает в среднем 17 секунд.

Comment: Что значит страница грузится? Выполните чисто запрос, без всякой вьюшки и посмотрите за сколько он отработал. Потом попрофилируйте запрос, если даже так долго выполняется - может там строится совсем другой запрос.

Comment: @Monk обновил вопрос. Посмотрите в UPD пожалуйста.

Comment: @Monk и как профилировать запрос в Windows?

Comment: @Monk к слову, в логах отладки Visual Studio всплывает вот такая строка `SELECT "m"."id", <...>, "m"."vote_average", "m"."vote_count"
FROM "Movies" AS "m"` это он при каждом запросе всю БД запрашивает  выходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies => context.Movies;
```

При обращении к этому свойству и получении результатов запроса сначала загрузится весь `Movies`, а потом будет применена фильтрация.

> Интерфейс IEnumerable находится в пространстве имен
>   System.Collections. Объект IEnumerable представляет набор данных в
>   памяти и может перемещаться по этим данным только вперед. Запрос,
>   представленный объектом IEnumerable, выполняется немедленно и
>   полностью, поэтому получение данных приложением происходит быстро.
>
> При выполнении запроса IEnumerable загружает все данные, и если нам
>   надо выполнить их фильтрацию, то сама фильтрация происходит на стороне
>   клиента.

https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.4.php

Замените `IEnumerable` на `IQueryable`. Тогда отбор будет произведён на стороне БД.

Comment: Не совсем. Тут происходит только копирование одного объекта, а загрузка всего - уже в ToList(). Но дело и правда в типе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, конечно.

Comment: О, блин.. Стоило догадаться. Спасибо, теперь грузится гораздо быстрее. Запрос из UPD возвращает 0.2 секунды, и View запускается быстро (на сколько это возможно для View). Плюс заметил, что в логах теперь вспылвает sql запрос не всей БД, а отфильтрованный запрос)